# Unable to start activity On Sony Experia S

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, sony

I recently published my app to the android play store.

I see a whole lot of error logs from one device in particular. It's a Sony Experia S.

I contacted the owner of the device, and he says he has the latest version of android ( don't know the exact version ).

I heard from a colluege developer that there are more known issieus with sony devices and android.

This app in particular works with fragments... Don't know if this is the problem but... Maybe the sony's don't know how to cope with them.

Does anyone have an idea what this problem could be.

Error logs looks like:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.crosscommunications.kvodeventer/com.crosscommunications.kvodeventer.KVODeventerActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.crosscommunications.kvodeventer/com.crosscommunications.kvodeventer.TabControllerHome}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.crosscommunications.kvodeventer/com.crosscommunications.kvodeventer.TabControllerHome}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1808)
at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:682)
at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:346)
at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:236)
at com.crosscommunications.kvodeventer.KVODeventerActivity.onCreate(KVODeventerActivity.java:27)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.crosscommunications.kvodeventer.KVOHome.onCreateView(KVOHome.java:52)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:870)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1080)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1416)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:505)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1136)
at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:4480)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1940)
... 21 more
```

Thnx

Comment: Looks like the cause is a `NullPointerException` at `com.crosscommunications.kvodeventer.KVOHome.onCreateView()` in `KVOHome.java` at line 52. Post that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put a null check to your code:

KVOHome Acvitivity, line 52.
at com.crosscommunications.kvodeventer.KVOHome.onCreateView(KVOHome.java:52)

Most probably, Sony sends a null value to your code.